# Bit resolution / Bit depth of microphone channel in Flash

Tags: flash, microphone

I need to figure out the bit depth / quantization / bit resolution of the microphone channel in Flash. Anybody out there, who knows that?

The sampling rate is pretty simple - one can set/get it with `Microphone.rate` (to 5,8,16,22 or 44 KHz).

But no clue about the bit depth. It's not mentioned at any Adobe pages as far as I know. There's no function to set or get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any info on bit depth for this either, so I assume the bit depth is 16 (i.e. 2 bytes per sample).

This should be easy to determine experimentally by just recording sound into a WAV file and seeing how large the file is.  The file size should be equal to:

```
fileSize = seconds * samplesPerSecond * bytesPerSample
```

So:

```
bytesPersample = fileSize / (seconds * samplesPerSecond)
```

Comment: Thanks. Sounds like a good work around. Will try something like this.